# Swift Cocoa - Selected checkbox cell in NSTableview

Tags: swift, cocoa, checkbox, nstableview

I'm learning to create a simple program in Cocoa swift. What I'm trying to do here is to create a tableview with 2 columns. One for CheckBox and one for TextView.

[Simple Cocoa app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1npK.png)

But I cannot change the checkbox state when click on the checkbox. What I need is when I click a checkbox, it's select that row on the tableview. Are there any event for the checkbox so I can check it?

Here is my code

```
import Cocoa

let Mydirectory: [String] = ["John", "Davis", "Mark", "Sarah", "Kim", 
"Hanna"]

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, 
NSTableViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func awakeFromNib() {

}

@IBOutlet weak var table: NSTableView!

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return Mydirectory.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {

    return Mydirectory[row]
}
}
```

Comment: One cannot tell whether you are using cell-based or view-based table.

Comment: i'm using a view-based table

Comment: Subclass NSTableCellView.

Comment: Connect the action of the checkbox to an action method of the table view delegate.

Comment: I did create the action for checkbox. When I click on a checkbox it acted like a button. The state didn’t change although i can let it print the table row when I clicked. By the way, I used cell based for the table view.

Comment: Use a view based table view unless you thoroughly understand why you have to use a cell based table view.